# Fill many shapes with different colors

Tags: microsoft-visio

I have a set of shapes. Can I automatically fill them with different colors like smart art can? Meaning instead of setting their fill color one by one?

Comment: There seems to be no effective way to do this. You can follow Paul's suggestion and use Themes to fill shapes with different colors.

Answer (score 1):

There is no version of SmartArt available for Visio. Visio has Themes to provide a range of colors to your shapes.